# Jooq combination of two working queries failing with FROM clause error

Tags: sql, postgresql, jooq

I have two queries that are working individually but when I attempt to combine them I am getting an error saying: "ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for Table "A".  The purpose of the queries is to look at the combined results of two tables which have a JSONB column in the format ["tag1","tag2","tag3"] with column name TAGS.  Individually both queries work but when I attempt to combine them I get the error.  I must be missing something but I've tried several approaches to no avail.  Any idea how to resolve this issue?  The result should be a distinct list of tags that match the query with a wildcard at the end.  Below are the queries and the combination of them.  I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.3

```
    final Field<String> value = field(name("A", "value"), String.class);

    final Table<Record1<String>> c1 = sql.dsl()
            .selectDistinct(value)
            .from(CAMPAIGN,lateral(table("jsonb_array_elements_text({0})", CAMPAIGN.TAGS)).as("A"))
            .where(CAMPAIGN.STORE_KEY.equal(campaign.getStoreKey()))
            .and(CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_KEY.notEqual(campaignKey))
            .and(value.like(search + "%%"))
            .asTable("c1");

    final Table<Record1<String>> c2 = sql.dsl()
            .selectDistinct(value)
            .from(STOREFRONT, lateral(table("jsonb_array_elements_text({0})", STOREFRONT.TAGS)).as("A"))
            .where(STOREFRONT.STORE_KEY.equal(campaign.getStoreKey()))
            .and(value.like(search + "%%"))
            .asTable("c2");

    final Result<Record1<String>> result = sql.dsl()
            .selectDistinct(value)
            .from(c1, c2)
            .limit(30)
            .fetch();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [Union](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/union-clause/). Try this (don't have a workspace with jooq to test, but something like this should work):

```
final Field<String> value = field(name("A", "value"), String.class);

final Select<Record1<String>> c1 = sql.dsl()
        .selectDistinct(value)
        .from(CAMPAIGN,lateral(table("jsonb_array_elements_text({0})", CAMPAIGN.TAGS)).as("A"))
        .where(CAMPAIGN.STORE_KEY.equal(campaign.getStoreKey()))
        .and(CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_KEY.notEqual(campaignKey))
        .and(value.like(search + "%%"));

final Select<Record1<String>> c2 = sql.dsl()
        .selectDistinct(value)
        .from(STOREFRONT, lateral(table("jsonb_array_elements_text({0})", STOREFRONT.TAGS)).as("A"))
        .where(STOREFRONT.STORE_KEY.equal(campaign.getStoreKey()))
        .and(value.like(search + "%%"));

final Result<Record1<String>> result = sql.dsl()
        .selectFrom(c1.asTable())
        .union(c2)
        .limit(30)
        .fetch();
```

Comment: I just tried that and it gives me the same error:

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "A"

Comment: I think I know why.. `value` is aliased as from table `A` which doesn't exist in the combined query.. try the last statement from my updated answer..

Comment: That worked! with one modification: selectFrom takes a Table passed in so I changed c1 to be Table<Record1<String>> and added .asTable("c1") to the end of the query.  After doing this it works as expected.  Thank you so much for your help!  I'm pretty terrible at doing anything more complicated than a basic select in jooq