# Can I combine these two JOOQ queries into one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jooq, postgresql-9.5

I have two queries which look at separate database tables and find items from a JSONB column in each table that are in the format ["tag1","tag2","tag3"] etc.  The purpose of the queries are to populate a list for a predictive dropdown i.e. if the list contains "dog" and the user types "d", "dog" should be returned.  Each of these queries works individually and I can easily combine them into a single JOOQ query?

```
    final Field<String> value = field(name("A", "value"), String.class);

    final Result<Record1<String>> res1 = sql.dsl()
            .selectDistinct(value)
            .from(CAMPAIGN,lateral(table("jsonb_array_elements_text({0})", CAMPAIGN.TAGS)).as("A"))
            .where(CAMPAIGN.STORE_KEY.equal(campaign.getStoreKey()))
            .and(CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_KEY.notEqual(campaignKey))
            .and(value.like(search + "%%"))
            .fetch();

    final Result<Record1<String>> res2 = sql.dsl()
            .selectDistinct(value)
            .from(STOREFRONT, lateral(table("jsonb_array_elements_text({0})", STOREFRONT.TAGS)).as("A"))
            .where(STOREFRONT.STORE_KEY.equal(campaign.getStoreKey()))
            .and(value.like(search + "%%")).fetch();
```

Comment: See the answer to your other question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39215810/2311919)

Answer (score 2):

Sure! In SQL, "combining" two queries is mostly implemented using `UNION [ ALL ]` (where `ALL` indicates that you want to maintain duplicates). In your case, write the following:

```
final Result<Record1<String>> result = 
sql.dsl()
   .select(value)
   .from(
        CAMPAIGN,
        lateral(table("jsonb_array_elements_text({0})", CAMPAIGN.TAGS)).as("A"))
   .where(CAMPAIGN.STORE_KEY.equal(campaign.getStoreKey()))
   .and(CAMPAIGN.CAMPAIGN_KEY.notEqual(campaignKey))
   .and(value.like(search + "%%"))
   .union(
    select(value)
   .from(
        STOREFRONT, 
        lateral(table("jsonb_array_elements_text({0})", STOREFRONT.TAGS)).as("A"))
   .where(STOREFRONT.STORE_KEY.equal(campaign.getStoreKey()))
   .and(value.like(search + "%%")))
   .fetch();
```

Note that I have replaced `selectDistinct()` by `select()`, because the `UNION` operation already removes duplicates, so there's no need to remove duplicates in each individual union subquery.